# Setting screen temperature using sct

Tags: linux-mint, graphics

I'm trying to set the screen temperature using both sct (https://github.com/faf0/sct). This is the command i'm running to set the temperature to 5000°k:

```
  sct 5000
```

and for a couple of seconds the screen temperature does change, but then it goes back to default.

I've also tried Redshift (https://github.com/jonls/redshift), but still the temperature isn't changing.

```
 System: Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

 Cinnamon Version: 5.2.7

 Linux Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic
```

Does anyone have any clue?
Cheers

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Now i'm running Linux Mint 21.1 and the issue seems to be gone.